# AngularJS Testing using Jasmine-Karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a factory service inside a folder,,,i have mentioned the path in karma.conf.js file correctly and added the angular-mocks before that..But 
if i try to load a factory/service which is not available in that folder then Unknown provider error is thrown

If i include the correct factory service then am not getting any error

But if i try to call a method in that factory/service,then the mocked service object is undefined and am getting cannot read a function from undefined error message..

I couldn't figure out why...can any1 help me in this issue..

**Spec.js**

```
describe('dfgh', function () {

var mockService,httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

  beforeEach(function () {

        inject(function ($httpBackend, _familyService_) {
            mockService = _familyService_;  
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        });

    });
    it('Factory Service Testing', function () {

        /// Code here

    });


});
```

**FamilySvc.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
    .factory('familyService', familyService);

    familyService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', 'service2', 'service3'];
    function familyService() {
        var a="Some String";
            return a;
    }
}());
```

**Karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'app/*.js', --> Holds FamilySvc.js
'tests/*.*' -- >holds Spec.js
],
```

Comment: If possible, please post some test case code.

Comment: module('app') is not a newly created module..It is an Existing module in the project

Comment: Is `FamilySvc.js` calling methods from `service2` and `service3`? Are they in app folder? Why haven't you mocked `service2` and `service3` in `Spec.js`?

Comment: Since i haven't used any methods in service2 and service 3..I dint mock those services....But even i try to mock them am getting unknown Provider error